# Excel VBA: Getting run-time 1004: Method Range of object _Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

On my UserForm Initialize I have the following code, but am getting an "run-time 1004: Method Range of object _Worksheet' failed" error, but it doesn't specify which line.  **I also included my Formulas at the bellow.**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim own As Range
Dim agr As Range
Dim serv As Range
Dim stat As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("DropDown")

For Each own In ws.Range("ownerlist2")
  With Me.Ownercb
    .AddItem own.Value
  End With
Next own

For Each agr In ws.Range("agrlist2")
  With Me.AGRcb
    .AddItem agr.Value
  End With
Next agr

For Each serv In ws.Range("servicelist2")
  With Me.TOScb
    .AddItem serv.Value
  End With
Next serv

For Each stat In ws.Range("statuslist2")
  With Me.Statuscb
    .AddItem stat.Value
  End With
Next stat

End Sub


ownerlist2:
**=OFFSET(DropDown!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(DropDown!$A:$A)-1,1)**

arglist2:
**=OFFSET(DropDown!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(DropDown!$B:$B)-1,1)**

servicelist2:
**=OFFSET(DropDown!$C$2,0,0,COUNTA(DropDown!$C:$C)-1,1)**

statustlist2:
**=OFFSET(DropDown!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(DropDown!$D:$D)-1,1)**
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i needed to change the formula scope to the right workbook